# How to tell Chef to install 32bit library ia32-libs on precise64?

Tags: chef-infra, 32-bit, i386

Normally this should work

```
package ia32-libs do
  action :install
end
```

... but I am getting that the package is no longer present in Ubuntu 12.04 repositories for a 64bit system.

So I found [this thread on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107230/what-happened-to-the-ia32-libs-package) that suggest to append `:i386` to the package name.

```
package "ia32-libs:i386" do
  action :install
end
```

... but `ia32-libs:i386` has no candidate in the apt-cache

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're right the package is no longer available in the repositories. The suggestion was made but it was not meant to be to use with the `ia32-libs` package.
For example if you wan't to install the 32 bit version of vlc, the package name would look like this `vlc:i386`.
In your case you should append the `:i386` part at the end of the package which you would like to install (you don't need the ia32-libs to do that).